# Perspective distortions correction

Tags: camera, geometry, computer-vision

I'm searching for a methods of text recognition based on document borders. 
Or the methods that can solve the problem of finding new viewpoint. 
For exmp. the camera is in point (x1,y1,z1) and the result picture with perspective distortions, but we can find (x2,y2,z2) for camera to correct picture.

Thanks.

Comment: [This Sudoku solver](http://sudokugrab.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/how-does-it-all-work.html) is an example for a related problem - it finds the corners of the printed square in the photo then finds a perspective transform that maps it to the unit square (though it does not care about camera coordinates.)  I think you need to be more specific with your question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach, which assumes that the document's page is approximately flat in 3D space, is to warp the quadrangle encompassing the page into a rectangle. To do so you must estimate a [homography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_%28computer_vision%29), i.e. a (linear) projective transformation between the original image and its warped counterpart.

The estimation requires matching points (or lines) between the two images, and a common choice for documents is to map the page corners in the original images to the image corners of the warped image. This will in general produce a rectangle with an incorrect aspect ratio (i.e. the warped page will look "wider" or "taller" than the real one), but this can be easily corrected if you happen to know in advance what the real aspect ratio is (for example, because you know the type of paper used, whether letter, A4, etc.).

A simple algorithm to perform the estimation is the so-called [Direct Linear Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linear_transformation).

The OpenCV library contains routines to help accomplishing all these tasks, look into it.